# How to implement rank function of SQL in mapreduce?

Tags: mapreduce, hive, rank

I have a situation where I need to replicate SQL rank function in mapreduce.
It is similar to this: QUALIFY Row_number() over(partition by a.column1 order by a.column2 desc, d.column3 desc) =1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> It is similar to this: QUALIFY Row_number() over(partition by
>   a.column1 order by a.column2 desc, d.column3 desc) =1

I'm sorry, I didn't quite get this. Are you trying to achieve this through hive or MR?Your question says that you need it through MR, but you have shown this query. Both are totally different.

You might find this [post](http://www.edwardcapriolo.com/roller/edwardcapriolo/entry/doing_rank_with_hive) useful if you want to achieve this through Hive. And if you want this MR way, you need to write your code from scratch.

HTH

Comment: Hi Tariq, I can do it in Hive, but we need to do the same in Mapreduce.I mean, we need to convert a hive query into mapreduce to show the client both hive and mapreduce performance.

Answer (score 0):

Given below is the replication of Rank function using a normal query.

This query will execute irrespective of the Database. The requirement is to Rank the filename based on the date in the filename.

```
**Sample Records**:
`insert into ref values('840001','840001_2015_04_29');
insert into ref values('840002','840002_2015_04_29');
insert into ref values('840003','840003_2015_04_29');
insert into ref values('840004','840004_2015_04_29');
insert into ref values('840008','840008_2015_04_28');
insert into ref values('840009','840009_2015_05_02');
insert into ref values('850005','850010_2015_05_29');
insert into ref values('850005','850010_2015_05_23');
insert into ref values('850005','850010_2015_05_12');
insert into ref values('850005','850010_2015_05_17');
insert into ref values('850006','850010_2015_05_29');
insert into ref values('850006','850010_2015_05_23');
insert into ref values('850006','850010_2015_05_16');`

`**Table Structure**:
CREATE TABLE ref
(
     ffid   TEXT
    ,filename       TEXT
);`

**Query**:
SELECT 
   S1.FFID
  ,S1.FILENAME
  ,(
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
    FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT FFID,FILENAME FROM REF) AS S2 
    WHERE S1.FFID=S2.FFID AND S1.FILENAME < S2.FILENAME
   ) AS RANK 
 FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT FFID,FILENAME FROM REF) AS S1
 WHERE RANK=1
 ORDER BY FFID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rank is implimented:

```
rank() over (partition by a.column1 order by a.column2 desc, d.column3 desc)
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics